# interface sharepoint <=> own independent web application

Tags: development, rest

I'm really sorry to annoy you with this, but I just don't get a clear answer though I try hard to find it. I've learned a lot about the REST interface - but it looks like that it is simply impossible to exchange data between SharePoint and a independently running (web based) application.

Does SharePoint (2013) have an exposed interface for web applications which run independently on their own server? We've got 'sharepoint.local' (Windows/IIS) and a 'webapp.local' (Unix/Apache) and both need to talk to each other. Everything is running company intern.

As far as I could figure out, REST doesn't help here, it requires the webapp to be integrated into the SharePoint-portal in some way. I tried registering the webapp as an Add-In, got keys etc. But the webapp can't get an AccessToken without running "inside" SharePoint somehow. So my assumption as a (clueless) SP-newbie is that SharePoint is some kind of "everything under one roof solution" by design?

Thanks a lot for your patience. The problem for me is that I get a ton of answers, but none helped so far to make this point clear.

Comment: Wich kind of interface are you depeloping? Batch, on line? Type and volumen of operations?

Comment: I developed a PHP/SQL/Ajax-based webapp which needs to read, write, delete documents stored in SharePoint. The company wants all documents to be stored in one central DB, atm my webapp stores documents in its own DB.

Comment: In this case I would develop an option that has good performance. My suggestion is to create a console application in C #. This application connects to your SQL engine PHP application to read documents. That application also connects to SharePoint (with Server Object Model) to read documents. Then you could store the documents in the central repository. I understand that would be a batch application that runs once a day or at certain intervals.